# How to send ReverseHello message periodically from OPC UA server to OPC UA client in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, opc-ua, node-opcua

I have developed OPC UA SERVER application using CSharp(C#) language.
I want to send periodically reverse hello messages to OPC UA Client.
I configured the configuration file in following way in OPC UA Server.
Please help it.

```
</ServerConfiguration>
  ...
  <ReverseConnect>
    <Clients>
      <ReverseConnectClient>
        <EndpointUrl>opc.tcp://localhost:65300</EndpointUrl>
        <Timeout>30000</Timeout>
      </ReverseConnectClient>
    </Clients>
    <ConnectInterval>15000</ConnectInterval>
    <ConnectTimeout>30000</ConnectTimeout>
    <RejectTimeout>60000</RejectTimeout>
  </ReverseConnect>
</ServerConfiguration>
```

Comment: The ReverseConnect service is a solution so server behind a firewall can be connected with a Client outside. This is not used for a heartbeat. I think most of the sdks handle this for you. You can check this with wireshark